# python structured/recarray type conversion behaviour

Tags: python, numpy, types, recarray

I'm confused by the behaviour of type conversion when constructing a structured/recarray:

This simple example takes in numerical fields but defines the type as string:

```
data = [(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)]
np.array(data, dtype=[('x', str), ('y', int)])
```

Which produces:

```
array([('', 2), ('', 4)], dtype=[('x', 'S'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

So the values were converted to empty strings which is not what you would expect from:

```
str(1.0)
```

Which produces the string `'1.0'`. What's causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify a string width, e.g. 'a3':

```
>>> np.array([(1.0, 2),(3.0,4)],dtype=[('x','a3'),('y',int)])
array([('1.0', 2), ('3.0', 4)], 
      dtype=[('x', 'S3'), ('y', '<i4')])
```

Just using `str` effectively means a string field of 0 bytes - which of course is too small to hold the string rendition of the float.